# Why CUDA is unavailable for using with easyocr?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, easyocr

According to [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/) I used this command in cmd

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
```

[image]

[image]

But CUDA still unavailable. Could someone help me, please?

```
import torch
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

The output will be `False`

Comment: Among the requirements for a proper CUDA install are that you need a CUDA-capable GPU, as well as a properly installed GPU driver of new enough version to support the software stacks (e.g. CUDA 11.3) that you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update driver first:

Here is a concept diagram from nvidia website

[image]

Here is another one:

[image]

More at [CUDA Compatibility](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, and the fix for me was uninstalling Pytorch and installing the Nightlys version with CUDA 12.1. I am using the CUDA Toolkit 12.3.

Run this and see if it's a smaller issue than updating drivers:

```
pip uninstall torch

pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu121
```

Just make sure your Pytorch version supports your corresponding CUDA Toolkit version, and neither mismatches the other. If this doesn't help, see the response from [@trsvchn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72353402/23071816) about updating drivers, or check if you meet the [system requirements](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html).

Figured out when I did:

```
python
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'2.1.2+cpu'
```

...and realized that I had the CPU version...

Comment: Thanks, btw my laptop has Intel HD Graphics 620, so unfortunately I can't use CUDA

Comment: Ah, that makes sense... gotta have the Nvidia GPUs :(

Answer (score 0):

You still have to install [cuda-toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and [cudnn](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html) on your machine