easyocr readtext ends with illegal instruction exception
I'm trying to process a very clear image with python's easyocr package.
This is my image: phonenum.png
Here is my code:
import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext('images/phonenum.png')

for (bbox, text, prob) in result:
    print(text)

I'm using python 3.12.7, easyocr 1.7.2, torch 2.5.1, torchvision 0.20.1, torchaudio 2.5.1, and opencv-python 4.10.0.84.  My CPU supports AVX.
I'm expecting some text output.
Here is the terminal output using pycharm:
C:\Users\charl\PYTHON\stackoverflow_questions_2\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\charl\PYTHON\stackoverflow_questions_2\read_text_ocr.py 
Neither CUDA nor MPS are available - defaulting to CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.

Process finished with exit code -1073741795 (0xC000001D)

Using debug, the code never reaches the for loop. Exit code 0xC000001D is an illegal instruction exception.
How can I get some text output?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74860631/easyocr-warning-cuda-not-available-defaulting-to-cpu-note-this-module-is-muc

@MSH, thanks. I did try one of the answers with no success. I don't have a CUDA GPU.
